# Visual Studio C# Xamarin - Android networking broadcast issue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, networking, broadcast

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to develop a cross-plaftorm project in C# Xamarin (Android, iOS, UWP).
I'm new to Android and cannot find the root cause of an issue... the UWP app on windows works like a charm.

I'm using the UdpClient's class as a server - binded to IPAddress.Any on a certain AppPort (e.g. 44444), also EnableBroadcast is true and ExclusiveAddressUse is false.
The client sends a broadcast message to 255.255.255.255 which the server should receive and process.

The issue is that this case is inconsistent, either:

1. The Android phone is getting the broadcast and everything works.

-or-

2. mUdpServer.Receive(...) blocks forever and I don't know the root cause (mUdpServer is UdpClient).

I suspect 2 options, either some kind of race on permission handling or some OS network related issue.

Permissions related facts:

- I'm requesting permissions on runtime a few lines before initializing the server binding.
- My requested permissions are CHANGE_NETWORK_STATUS, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATUS and INTERNET.
- The permissions seems to always granted immediately.

Network related facts:

- Wireshark on the client proves the broadcast was sent.
- PCs in the same network sees that broadcast.
- Installed PCAP Remote app on my Android device, cannot see relevant packets and cannot tell if that app is reliable.

So these are my questions:

- Any reliable pcap recorder app for Android?
- Are there any methods to see a log of my app on the phone? (using log4net - doesn't show logs on debug mode)
- Does C# have a way of enforcing usage in a specific network interface (e.g. Wifi)?

Comment: Broadcast messages do not get forwarded outside the subnet (determined by the mask).  Do you have any routers or hubs between transmitting PC and Android?  Bubs and Routes a usually set to default not to forward Broadcast messages.  So either one of 3 things need to happen 1) Put Android IP address inside the subnet mask 2) Change Subnet mask in router/hub to include Android IP 3) Change setting on hub router to forward Broadcast messages.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, all PCs are linked via 1 access point and plain old switches. I don't think that's the direction since the app sometimes work completely and sometimes don't. 
More likely it is some kind of race condition on the phone.
I'll update the query with some more info...

Comment: Can you run netstat to see status when it works and doesn't work?  It is possible that another app is intercepting the messages so check who is getting the port number may be a clue.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681066/is-the-netstat-command-generically-available-on-android

Comment: good direction. I tried "netstat -n" which came back with no actual results, probably should have tried "netstat -s", do I need special permissions for that?

Comment: Try 'a' option which gives ALL.

Comment: Hi, my network is 192.168.1.x.
Client is 192.168.1.164. Server is 192.168.1.127.
Client was listening on a port, when the server sent to 255.255.255.255 - no receive.
192.255.255.255 - no receive
192.168.255.255 - no receive
192.168.1.255 - no receive
192.168.1.164 - unicast received! which means it was listening.
I checked and EnableBroadcast was true.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at port number and check status.  What IP are you sending to?  I do not think you should be sending to 255.255.255.255 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address).  Normally the subnet broadcast address is the highest in the subnet (192.168.1.255 or 192.168.X.255) depending on the mask.  Usually you will be blocked from sending to 255.255.255.255.  I don't have a lot of experience with Protocols using Broadcast.  I just know I tried a couple of times and it didn't work and didn't do a lot of investigating.

Comment: If not receiving that there must be an application on machine that is intercepting the port number and not forwarding to your application.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.joinmulticastgroup?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help so far.
I sent a unicast to this client and it does receive it (when failed to listen for broadcast), it means that this is the sole listener on that port, so IMO that cannot be the issue.
I tried to send to 192.168.X.255 in the same case but it didn't work.
I narrowed the issue down to the Android device, I think EnabledBroadcast doesn't work in some cases.
It is reproduced if I open the App when Wifi is off - when turn it back on (I have a broadcast receiver and it switches to the interface IP) the App is incapable of intercepting broadcasts.

Comment: When an IP is received on a windows machine by the internet card is the is a linked list of apps that are registered to receive the IP (listeners). The message is than sent to first app that is registered.  So if you are not seeing an IP than either another device is getting the message, the operating system is not accepting the protocol, or the port is being blocked,  The best way of seeing what is happening is using Netstat -a (all).  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681066/is-the-netstat-command-generically-available-on-android

Comment: @jdweng - this is the netstat -a output:
[0:] Active Internet connections (established and servers)
[0:] Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
[0:] Active UNIX domain sockets (established and servers)
[0:] Proto RefCnt Flags  Type     State     I-Node Path

what do I miss?

Comment: Looks like you have a linux kernel.  I'm not really good a debugging these issues.  I seen lots of issues with IP messaging between the windows and linux operating system on same machine.  Not sure how to fix.

Comment: thank you for trying :)

Comment: I got to use adb shell to check the client's listening ports and it does listens to the correct port when the issue occurs. I also isolated the issue to the phone.
Opened a bug to microsoft to handle that UdpClient's misbehavior.

Comment: @jdweng

found out how to reproduce it - when I turn off and on the wifi that issue occurs, the receive doesn't receive broadcasts (but it does unicasts).

opened an Android related question - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62706186/android-udpclient-broadcast-listener-receives-only-after-locking-and-unlocking-t

hopefully someone already encountered and solved it.

Comment: Broadcast doesn't get forward through routes.  So you must be on different subnets (determined by mask).  A broadcast message get send to the highest mask in the subnet usually 255 or 255.255 where the subnet is determined by mask.  This is not a Android issue it is the mask, subnet, and routers.

Comment: I know for a fact that the listener's network interface is getting the broadcast packets.
The program works perfectly when I enter it with the Wifi already activated on the phone.
I've done some investigation and found out that to reproduce the issue I just turn off the wifi and then turns it on (the app is closed), when I start the app and start the listener it is halted on UdpClient.Receive.
As a workaround, I lock the phone and unlock it, then bind the UdpClient and it is receiving the broadcast packets. you can see it got nothing to do with networking settings or equipment in the end...

Comment: See following : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: I needed an Android Multicast lock - solved!
Thanks :)