# Android UdpClient broadcast listener receives only after locking and unlocking the phone

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-wifi, broadcast

In spite the subject - this is an android question.
I'm relatively new to Android architecture and I'm working with c# xamarin over visual studio. I have a UdpClient class which works as expected receiving broadcast messages from Wifi.
**I have a bug in the program** - I noticed if I disconnect from my wifi network and reconnect - the new UdpClient doesn't receive and process any broadcast packets (it does receive unicast).

Found out after days of investigation that when I lock the phone and unlock it when the Wifi is connected, suddenly everything works perfectly. My hunch tells me that way I'm resetting something in the Android OS and that I could somehow do it without locking/unlocking the phone.

I have created a broadcast receiver to track the network changes but I cannot see any difference between the values of a network before and after lock/unlock.
Any ideas? someone already solved it somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use a foreground serveice to check the wifi if connected in the background, if wifi re-connect, re-new your UdpClient.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry I see I didn't state it - there is no UdpClient instance in that stage of the program.
I use a BroadcastReceiver that is registered to "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE". and getting the WifiManager from the Wifi context. so to your question, no service, events.
What shall a foreground service do except renewing the UdpClient? Is there way to bind the app to a network interface somehow? (don't know, maybe that's what lock\unlock is allowing...)

Comment: I needed a WifiMulticast lock - solved!

Comment: If yu solved this issue, please share your solution to answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I'll share it. the solution can be seen here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock
The multicast lock is essential for receiving broadcast messages, I asked for this lock from the android context (similar to WifiLock which keep the wifi on when sleeping), and Acquired it to let the OS pass my socket the broadcast messages. Don't forget to Release the same lock you acquired. good luck.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing.